# How to expose minikube service urls to outside system

Tags: apache, apache-camel, kubernetes, minikube

I 've apache camel application deployed on kubernetes. My application is esposed in kubernetes cluster which is accessible at http://192.168.99.100:31750. so how to make it accessiible accross.

Comment: How are your YAML files? What is the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do 2 things :

- run an NginX Ingress Controller in your minikube and expose it with NodePort service. Meaning it will be available somewhat similar to your service right now (high port range)
- run HAProxy on your host that runs minikube that will forward 80/443 port to your high ports on minikube (ie. 80->32080, 443->32443)

that way you can expose your ingress controller on standard ports and have your services exposed with regular kubernetes Ingress definitions on these ports.

Comment: Do you have some sample example for this scenerio?

Comment: frontend microservice_http_appid_in
  bind *:81
  mode http
  option httplog
  acl getcareworkflow path_beg -i /MainetService/rest/mobility/grievance/getCareWorkflowMasterDefinedDepartmentsListByOrgId/{orgid}
  use_backend getcareworkflow if getcareworkflow

backend getcareworkflow
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  #http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port 81
  #http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  server 192.168.99.100 192.168.99.100:32618 weight 1 maxconn 512 check

Comment: above is the haproxy config I 've written but it is not connecting to the minikube server

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-01-25T13:29:21Z
  labels:
    app: default-http-backend
  name: default-http-backend
  namespace: foobar
  resourceVersion: "1917132"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/foobar/services/default-http-backend
  uid: c0604e09-01d3-11e8-8ce7-08002788a9d9
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.105.150.178
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32618
    port: 30488
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30488
  selector:
    app: default-http-backend
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

Comment: And Above is my Igress controller config. Please let me know anything is missing here.